# How do you enable work item dialog in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services)?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am trying to figure out why when I use VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) that I get VSTS opening the work items in a dialog box instead of a new page loading with the content and others on my team are not able to see this. Every time when someone opens a work item, they are always redirected to a new page instead of a dialog box showing up. Is this a feature and where can one change this behavior?

To be clear, I am talking about the existing functionality of VSTS and not the new preview feature around navigation.

Comment: Are you able to share a screenshot for your work item and your team member? Do you use the same browser?

Comment: Different panel has different behaviors. Where did you see this issue? Backlog or query result?

Comment: So my colleague figured this out. The way to change the behavior is to use the "Enter or exit full screen mode" toggle on the top right hand corner of the work item editor which is right next to the "X" button to close the editor. Once you toggle this button, you will begin seeing the editor open in a pop-up mode instead of a full screen mode everywhere.
Here is a link to the button I am referencing:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#work-items-page-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following URL, you can find documentation that talks about the toggle for "Full screen" mode for the work item editor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/work-items/view-add-work-items?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#work-items-page-controls

Here is a screenshot of this button which is referenced in the above documentation that will change the behavior of showing work items in a pop-up instead of loading in the entire page.

[image: VSTS - show work items in a pop-up]

Answer (score 1):

In VSTS, there are two views now. If you enable `New Navigation` preview feature, you'll see the new view.

[image]

New:

[image]

Old:

[image]

Comment: I know of the new preview feature but I am having this issue with the existing/non-preview functionality and was hoping that I am just missing some simple setting or there is a hidden feature that no one knows about that enables this capability because I've been looking for a long time.

Comment: Are you able to share a screenshot for your work item and your team member? Do you use the same browser?